# Reading a JSON file on a Linux Agent and Deploying it on DCOS

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to build a Automated Build and release pipeline on Azure DevOps.
I have a build pipeline which picks the code from Azure Repo and upon success it generates a Artifact package that needs to be deployed in DCOS which is my container Orchestration, Now I have a JSON file which gives me the config and other environment variables that are needed for deployment.

The JSON file is placed in the new folder in Azure Repo where my current code exists.

**Agent** : hosted Linux machine

**Current Task**:
Generating a new Artifact just to read the JSON file from the folder location in Azure Repo and now write a PowerShell script in the release pipeline task and deploy it into the DCOS along with the original package.

**Error**:
The power shell script below executes reads the JSON file but reads only partial, it does not read the parameters inside an array.

**JSON File**:

```
    {
  "id": "",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.05,
  "mem": 256,
  "disk": 0,
  "gpus": 0,
  "fetch": [
    {
      "uri": "",
      "extract": true,
      "executable": false,
      "cache": false
    }
  ],
  "storeUrls": [],
  "backoffSeconds": 1,
  "backoffFactor": 1.15,
  "maxLaunchDelaySeconds": 3600,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "",
      "network": "USER",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "servicePort": 10255,
          "name": "pocs",
          "labels": {
            "VIP_0": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "privileged": false,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": true
    }
  },
  "healthChecks": [],
  "readinessChecks": [],
  "dependencies": [],
  "upgradeStrategy": {
    "minimumHealthCapacity": 1,
    "maximumOverCapacity": 1
  },
  "ipAddress": {
    "groups": [],
    "networkName": "dcos"
  },
  "unreachableStrategy": {
    "inactiveAfterSeconds": 300,
    "expungeAfterSeconds": 600
  },
  "killSelection": "YOUNGEST_FIRST",
  "requirePorts": false,
  "env": {
    "BaseAddress:QueryServiceAddress": "",
    "ElasticSettings:Password": "",
    "ElasticSettings:NodeList:2": "",
    "ElasticSettings:IndexFilter:TypeIndexMapping:0:IndexMap": "",
    "ElasticSettings:Username": "",
    "serilog.sinks.kafka:topic": "",
    "ElasticSettings:NodeList:0": "",
    "LOCATION": "development",
    "ElasticSettings:NodeList:1": "",
    "CurrentIndex": "",
    "ElasticSettings:"",
    "serilog.sinks.kafka:kafka:bootstrap.servers": "",
    "loglevel": "Debug"
  }
```

**My script**:

```
$defaultWorkingDir=$env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY
$pathToJson = "$defaultWorkingDir/_SG-PO-APLL-CommandService-CI/JSONfiles/dev-template.json"

$a = Get-Content -Raw $pathToJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$a | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32| Set-Content "$defaultWorkingDir/_SG-PO-APLL-CommandService-CI/JSONfiles/dev-template.json"
Write-Host $a
```

Above reads Container but not the parameters inside the Array

I tried different solutions but nothing is working as the Agent is linux and it is asking for an system assembly which consists default methods and functions so that I can write a loop and it will work.

As the Agent is a hosted linux machine I have no idea how I can add system Assembly package,

**Approach 2**: Python Script

```
import json

data = json.loads(open('var/vsts/r2/a/_SG-PO-APLL-CommandService-CI/JSONfiles/dev-template.json').read())
data
```

This Python script reads the whole JSON file but it is not taking my default directory SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY but it accepts the location if I specify var/vsts/r2/a

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect, can you give a correct JSON example?

Comment: The script works fine for me on Hosted Ubuntu 1604 agent. How do you know it isn't  reads parameters?

Comment: I cannot provide the exact JSON file as it is security Issue. I was trying some thing with Bash script yesterday and it went well, The bash script task in my release pipeline works completely fine it picks the JSON file from the Azure repo along with the Artifact package generated during the build process and deploy's into my container which is DCOS.

But again this process needs a complete JSON file which is still manual process we are doing. I want to provide JSON template in the repo and separately at the time of release I want to provide variables separately in the release pipeline how?

Comment: I have updated the JSON file Please  have a look into it, 
Where am I at? - If the above JSON file is provided with all the parameters in it and it is placed in the Azure Repo folder my Bash script in the release pipeline succeeds deployment but I do not want to give all the parameters in the JSON file before the build I would like to add variables at the time of release pipeline. So how can I do that?

Comment: The Bash Script: That is working 
!/bin/sh

echo ${SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY} 

curl -v -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d @${SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY}/path_to
_JSON_file <URL-where it has to deploy>